# Responsive web page not working

Tags: html, css, responsive

I'm a beginner for responsive web designing. I created one page but when I try to check on different devices it is not working. Here is my code and screen shots.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device=width, initial-scale=1" charset="utf-8">
```

@charset "utf-8";

```
section, article, header, footer, nav, aside, hgroup {
display: block;
}



 /*-----------------------
    Global Styles
 -------------------------*/
 .clearfix:before,
 .clearfix:afetr{
    content:"";
    display:table;   
 }
 .clearfix:after{
    clear:both;
 }
 /*.clearfix{
 zoom:1;/*for IE6/7 trigger hasLayout
 } */



   /*-----------------------
    Navigation
 -------------------------*/

 nav ul{
     margin:0;
     padding:0;
     float:right;
 }
 nav ul li{
    list-style:none;
    float:left;

 }
 header nav ul li a{
     display:block;
     color:#FFF;
     text-decoration:none;
     font-weight:bold;
     padding:20px;
 }
header nav ul li a:hover{background-color:#003; }
     /*background:#67A6B8;*/

header nav ul li a:active{
     color: yellow;
    background-color: #003;
    text-decoration: underline;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)insert;
    -moz-box-shadow:0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)insert; 
    box-shadow:0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)insert;
  }
  header nav ul li a:visited{`enter code here`
      background-color:#9F3;
  }
```

I have tried for 2 weeks now. Please someone help me..

[image]

Comment: Maybe you should start with the example on [this](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp) website.

Answer (score 2):

Start by moving `charset="utf-8"` to its own meta tag, like so:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Also check for typos: you wrote `device=width` what should actually be `device-width`.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have correct my code but didn't work. Do I have to change style sheet also?

Comment: That's hard to say without knowing how your stylesheet currently looks like. Please consider editing your original question above and add a boiled down version of your stylesheet, that is: it doesn't have to contain *all* style definitions, but should contain media queries if used. Even better: create a little demo using http://codepen.io/pen/

Comment: I have added my scc file.Could you please help me to solve the problem.

Comment: I'd like to point out a whole bunch of typos: `clearfix:afeter` should be `after`, `box-shadow` can be `inset` but not `insert` and on your `header nav ui li a:visited` rule there should be no `enter code here` at all. At this point I'll join Jeroen's recommendation and point you to a tutorial. Please work through this http://learn.shayhowe.com/advanced-html-css/responsive-web-design/